# Matching list with agentset, or converting list into agentset or vice versa in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I have a model of customers and servers interacting; which is a kind of queueing model.
But customers have to visit in the specific order.

I put that order with choosers ; which is just a number. and finally made a list with it.

e.g. C1order = ["server 0", "server 1" ...]

It means Customer 1 have to visit server 0 first, server 1 second, and so on.

I set customers to visit `first` (C1order).
and after the first visit, I'll use `but-first` C1order.

So next time, I could make it visit next server.

and next-server is agentset. So, as C1order is a list, cannot match with agentset("server 0" does not means server 0).

How can I program it?

I've tried  so many ways, like, next-server `with` [ label = "customer 0"]
or `let` new-next-server (list next-server).

But it failed. What can I do? Thank you in advance!

My netlogo version is 6.2.0

Answer (score 1):

the list as you've created it `["server 0"....` is a list of character strings. What you want is a list of agents, something like `(list server 1 server 2 server 3)`